# Kotlin, Jackson ignores JsonDeserialize annotation on parent class

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson, json-deserialization

I have to parse json that comes to me in this format, for simplicity I only left 2 fields:

- Example 1 (single value): {"instruction":"say hello", "trigger":"next_step"}
- Example 2 (list of values): {"instruction":"say hello", "trigger":["next_step", "another_step"]}

I want to model trigger field as a list of strings, where example 1 should be converted to list of length 1. I setup a base class that has trigger property and I have bunch of subclasses that add additional data. Here is an example:

```
open class BaseInstruction @JsonCreator constructor(

    @JsonProperty("instruction")
    val instruction: String? = "",

    @JsonDeserialize(using = TriggerDeserializer::class)
    @JsonProperty("trigger")
    open val trigger: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
)

data class MagicInstruction @JsonCreator constructor(
    @JsonProperty("name")
    var name: String? = null,
): BaseInstruction(instruction = null, trigger = mutableListOf())


class TriggerDeserializer : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer<MutableList<String>>() {
    override fun deserialize(p: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, ctxt: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext): MutableList<String> {
        val rootNode: JsonNode = p.codec.readTree(p)
        return when {
            rootNode.isTextual -> mutableListOf(rootNode.asText())
            rootNode.isArray -> rootNode.map { it.asText() }.toMutableList()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid format for send_trigger")
        }
    }
}
```

The following test code demos the problem, when I try to parse simple JSON into MagicInstruction class then I get an exception:

```
fun main() {
    val jsonStringSingle = """{"instruction":"say hello", "trigger":"next_step"}"""
    val jsonStringList = """{"instruction":"say hello", "trigger":["next_step", "another_step"]}"""

    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    val instructionSingle = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStringSingle, MagicInstruction::class.java)
    val instructionList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStringList, MagicInstruction::class.java)

    println(instructionSingle)
    println(instructionList)
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.ArrayList` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('next_step')
 at [Source: (String)"{"instruction":"say hello next step", "trigger":"next_step"}"; line: 1, column: 49])
```

If I change type to BaseInstruction then everything works and JsonDeserialize is applied properly.

```
val instructionSingle = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStringSingle, BaseInstruction::class.java)
```

For some reason Jackson ignores JsonDeserialize when it is on a parent class.

I was able to work around this problem by defining trigger as its own class with 2 constructors.

```
data class TriggerList @JsonCreator constructor(val names: List<String> = mutableListOf()) {
        @JsonCreator
        constructor(name: String) : this(listOf(name))
    }
```

However, I'm really curious to understand why my original approach is not working.